# What can you do with a server/host besides host websites?

Tags: html, sql, database, hosting

What can you do with a a server besides Host websites ?
e.g. backup files , anything else ?

I have a free server with unlimited space , anything I can make useful or cool out of it ?
Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it really isn't about a specific programming/coding problem or issue at all.

Comment: For the record, you can host a lot of things on a server ... a mail server, a proxy server,  a game server, a torrenting server ... if you do a lot of computation you could even use your server to run your programs so they are running when you turn off your computer, etc.  if you are comfortable with the command line you could even ditch your actual computer (and just use a dumb one with a terminal) and do everything via SSH.  Or maybe VCN into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything you can do with a computer.
Except it is somewhere else (not home based server).

You can use it for online storage, hosting (web, app, game), as proxy server, remote desktop for any reason.